# Syncfusion WPF DoubleTextBox wrong Formating with Min and MaxValue and MinValidation and MaxValidation

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, syncfusion

I am using the Syncfusion WPF components in my Projekt and found a strange formating issue with the DoubleTextBox.
So my Double TextBox looks like this:

```
<syncfusion:DoubleTextBox Width="70"
                        MinValue="100"
                        MinValidation="OnLostFocus"
                        MaxValue="1000"
                        MaxValidation="OnLostFocus"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        NumberDecimalDigits="3"
                        Value="{Binding SamplingNumber}">
</syncfusion:DoubleTextBox>
```

So the expected behavior would be that I can input whatever I want(something like 52) and when I lose focus the value jumps to the MinValue.
Now this works as long as everything is selected or STRG + A is pressed.
As soon as I get the cursor in the field I cant input a value under a min or over the max.

For example:
I put my cursor in the field press ctrl + A and I type 56 everything works fine.
Now I do the same thing put my cursor in the field without selecting all I can't remove anything or input anything below 100

Is there a setting or something that I can do to fix this, or should I make my own version of this with the normal Textbox?

Is there a way around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are glad to announce that requested issue is fixed and included in our Essential Studio 2020 Volume 3 release v18.3.0.35 which is available for download under the following link.

https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/158306/essential-studio-2020-volume-3-release-v18-3-0-35-is-available-for-download

We thank you for your support and appreciate your patience in waiting for this release. Please get in touch with us if you would require any further assistance.We have included your requested issue “Syncfusion WPF DoubleTextBox Wrong Formatting with Min and MaxValue and MinValidation and MaxValidation".

Regards,
Elakkiya

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your update.

We are able to reproduce the reported issue and we have logged it as bug. The fix for this issue will be included in Volume 3 release which will roll out by end of September 2020. We appreciate your patience until then.

Regards,
Niranjan Kumar Gopalan

Answer (score 0):

We could able to reproduce the reported behavior at our end. Currently, we are validating this behavior. For more information refer to the Syncfusion support ticket.

Regards,
Aiswarya